# Sidekiq worker not getting triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, sidekiq

I am using [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) for my background jobs:

**I have a worker app/workers/data_import_worker.rb**

```
class DataImportWorker
 include Sidekiq::Worker
 sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(job_id,file_name)
    begin
    #Some logic in it .....
  end
 end
```

**Called from a file lib/parse_excel.rb**

```
  def parse_raw_data
      #job_id and #filename are defined bfr
      DataImportWorker.perform_async(job_id,filename)   
  end
```

As soon as i trigger it from my action the worker is not getting called.. Redis is running on `localhost:6379`

Any idea why this must be happening.  The Environment is Linux.

Comment: Is sidekiq running? What does it say in the log? Did you check redis, is the job added to queue:default ?

Comment: @Roman: Thanks for reply! yes sidekiq and redis both are running .. the job is also not getting added to default queue... but when i trigger job from console it works

Comment: Perhaps you've different databases or namespaces when running in development and production. Or a different queue is set up.

Comment: @Roman: didn't get you.. can u elaborate please?

Comment: I'm referring to this: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had a similar problem where Sidekiq was running but when I called `perform_async` it didn't do anything except return `true`.

The problem was **rspec-sidekiq** was added to my "*:development, :test*" group. I fixed the problem by moving **rspec-sidekiq** to the "*:test*" group only.

Comment: This was the similar problem in my case

Comment: I had the same exact issue. I had to rebuild my bundle as well: `bundle install --without test`

Comment: I added a link to this answer at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#the-workers-are-not-starting for future reference

Comment: thank you for the providing your answer, I was about to throw my machine ou the window.

Comment: also see https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq for a call out of this potential issue

Answer (score 8):

Start sidekiq from the root directory of your Rails app. For example,

> bundle exec sidekiq -e staging -C config/sidekiq.yml

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem, it turns out that the argument I've passed in the function perform_async is not appropriate, it seems that one should not pass any query result in perform_async, you must do all the query in the function perform.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the name of the queue that worker is for.

Example:
sidekiq_options retry: false, **:queue => data_import_worker**

data_import_worker can be any name you want to give it.

Then when you go to the web interface: yoursite.com/sidekiq, you'll be able to see the current workers for the queue "data_import_worker"

Answer (score 1):

For me when doing a perform_later, it would enqueue but never remove from queue. I needed to add my queue name to the sidekiq.yml file

```
---
:concurrency: 25
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:queues:
  - default
  - my_queue
```

Answer (score 1):

Lost a good 15 min on this. To check if Sidekiq is correctly loading your config file (with the queues names), go to the web interface in the Busy tab and you'll find your Process ID and below it you'll find your queues.

In our case, we had misspelled `mailer` (the correct ActiveJob queue for Mailers is `mailers`, in plural).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was simply having the worker file in the wrong path.

Needs to be in "project_root/app/worker/worker.rb", not "project_root/worker/worker.rb"

Check the file path!

Answer (score 0):

is it realy run multiple workers on standalone sidekiq?
for example I have 2 workers:
ProccessWorker
CallbackWorker

when I am runnigs sidekiq:
bundle exec sidekiq -r ./workers/proccess_worker.rb -C ./config/sidekiq.yml

only one worker in same time.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling `perform_async(23)` in a production console, however my sidekiq was started in staging mode.

After I started the Sidekiq in production mode, things have started working very well.